# True false question related to graph having a unique Minimum weight spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

- You have an undirected graph $G$
- $G$ has a cycle in it
- That cycle has an edge $e$
- e is a unique lightest weight edge in that cycle

Is it true that $e$ is part of every Minimum weight spanning tree of $G$?

I cant find any example to disprove this statement so I am assuming it is true. Do you think the same? or can you find a counter example?

Comment: Does $G$ have only that one cycle, or can it have others?

Comment: @DanielFischer it can have other cycles also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII art:

```
    A---1---B
    |\     /|
    | 1   1 |
    |  \ /  |
    1   C   1
    |  / \  |
    | 2   3 |
    |/     \|
    D---4---E
```

Consider the cycle $CDE$.